# Parallel tournament. How to return the position of the maximum value of an array

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

I need to write an algorithm to find the position of the maximum value using parallel tournament. I have this code to find the maximum value:

> // Shared memory variables n: values   M[0..n-1]: array with values
>
> // Procedure in parallel
>
> ```
> torneoMaxParalelo(M,n)
> int incr=1;
> int grande, temp0, temp1; 
> while (incr < n)
>
>     temp0 ← M[pid];
>     if (pid + incr < n)
>        temp1 ← M[pid + incr];
>     else
>        temp1 ← -infinite;
>     grande ← max(temp0, temp1);
>     M[pid] ← grande;
>     incr = 2 * incr;
> ```

The algorithm should take O(log n) time. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean O(log n) time?  Omega(log n) time means "asymptotically no faster than," so a linear search would be Omega(log n) time.

Comment: What parallel model are you targeting?

Comment: if this is homework, tag it as such (nothing wrong with asking for help here; just make it clear that it's homework so that people can help without giving the answer away outright)

Comment: Ahh, ok. I already did it. Here´s the code.

Comment: If you have solved the problem your self you should make that solution an *answer* rather than putting it into the question. That kind of self-answering is encouraged and it lets people provide separate feedback on your question and your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here´s the  pseudocode.

```
 parTournMaxIndex(M, idx, n)  
 int incr;  
 Write -infinite (some very
 small value) into M[n].  
 Write pid into idx[pid] and write n into idx[pid+n].
 incr = 1;  
 int idx0, idx1, idxBig;  
 Key key0, key1;
 while (incr < n) 
    Read idx[pid] into idx0 and read idx[pid+incr] into idx1.  
    Read M[idx0] into key0 and read M[idx1] into key1.  
    if (key1 > key0) idxBig = idx1; 
    else idxBig = idx0;  
    Write idxBig into idx[pid].  
    incr = 2 * incr;
```